# Different Control Behavior based on the type of the Binding in Silverlight

Tags: binding, silverlight-5.0

I have a custom UserControl in Silverlight which in all simplicity is composed of TextBlocks and TextBoxes. I have a hierarchy of class entities as follows:

- Person is an abstract super class that contains the properties Name and Age
- Man is a child of Person that adds the property FacialFeature
- Woman is a child of Person that adds the property LastMenstruated and HasHymen

So:

- a Person contains the properties Name and Age
- a Man contains the properties Name, Age and FacialFeature
- a Woman contains the properties Name, Age, LastMenstruated and HasHymen

What I want is for my UserControl to simply display the values of those properties like so:

if Person is of type Man:

```
Name : Mark
Age : 23
FacialFeature : Fully Shaved
```

or if Person is of type Woman:

```
Name : Jane
Age : 8
LastMenstruated : Never
HasHymen : Yes
```

Bear in mind this is a simplified example for the sake of my question.

**What I want is for my UserControl to display different information and possibly display it differently depending on the run-time type of Person.**

I have thought about creating the control in the code-behind using a switch statement that would switch on GetType(Person), but what I don't like about this, is that the logic would be in the UserControl. I would like a solution that has the objects encapsulate their own display, so that if I add new types of Person, I don't need to go back to the UserControl and add in a case for the new types, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking your male/female split as an example you need to bind the `Visibilty` of the elements to the object being displayed through a converter that takes a parameter:

```
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding SelectedPerson,
                        Converter={StaticResource GenderConverter},
                        ConverterParameter=Male)" />
```

Then in your converter:

```
public class GenderConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((value is Man && parameter == "Male") ||
             value is Woman && parameter == "Female"))
            return Visibility.Visible;
        else
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This means that you don't have to add arbitrary UI properties to your classes to get them to display how you want them to.

*I'm not 100% sure of the tests for the object type (I don't have Silverlight 5 installed on this machine)*

More information on the [`IValueConverter` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) can be found on the MSDN.

Comment: Great, that's pretty much what I wanted. I changed it a bit. My converter simply returns "Visibility.Visible". And the binding has a "FallbackValue=Collapsed". This way, if I bind on Person.FacialFeature, the control will be hidden if the binding fails (because person would be a Woman) or it succeeds and is set to Visible through the converter, therefore displaying the control. This way, I don't even need if else logic in my converter.